# How can I verify $(I-UV^T)^{-1}=I+(UV^T)/(1+V^T U)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $U = [u_1, u_2,\dots ,u_n]^T$ and  $V= [v_1,v_2\dots,v_n]^T$ two column vectors. Let $A$ be the matrix $UV^T$.

How can I verify 
$(I-A)^{-1}=I+(UV^T)/(1+V^T U)$?

I couldn't approach any idea...

Comment: U = [u1 u2 u3 u4...un]   V= [v1 v2 v3 v4...vn]

Comment: What do you mean by "verify matrix"?

Comment: Please us MathJax to format the mathematics in your question. See here for a quick introduction: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @matthew In my opinion it should be $(I+(UV^T)/(1−V^TU))$. Do you mind to tell me what is your opinion?

Comment: that's right thank you for adjusting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will show that if $s:=V^TU=\sum_{k=1}^n v_k u_k\not=1$  and $A:=UV^T$ then $I-A$ is invertible and
$$(I-A)^{-1}=I+(UV^T)/(1-V^T U)$$
(there should be  a minus sign at the denominator in the right-hand side).

We first note that $A=[u_iv_j]$. Hence
$$A^2=\left[\sum_{k=1}^n (u_iv_k)(u_kv_j)\right]=\left[u_iv_j\sum_{k=1}^n v_ku_k\right]=s[u_i v_j]=sA.$$
Let us assume that $s\not=1$
$$B:=\left(I+\left(UV^T\right)/\left(1-V^TU\right)\right)=I+\frac{A}{1-s}$$
then
$$(I-A)B=(I-A)\left(I+\frac{A}{1-s}\right)=I-A+\frac{A}{1-s}-\frac{A^2}{1-s}\\
=I-A+\frac{A}{1-s}-\frac{sA}{1-s}=I+\frac{-(1-s)A+A-sA}{1-s}=I.$$
In a similar way, we verify that $B(I-A)=I$. Hence $B=(I-A)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

To verify it, show that

$$\left(I-A\right)\left(I+\left(UV^T\right)/\left(1+V^TU\right)\right)=I$$