# Find a matrix equation equivalent to $A^TPA+P=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Question was

Let $$A= \left[\begin{matrix} 
        a_1 & a_2\\
         a_3&a_4\\
       \end{matrix}\right]$$
$$P= \left[\begin{matrix} 
        p_1 & p_2\\
         p_3&p_4\\
       \end{matrix}\right]$$

Find the matrix $Q$ such that

$$ Q\left[
    \begin{array}
      \\
      p_1\\p_3\\p_2\\p_4
    \end{array}
\right] = \left[
    \begin{array}
      \\
      1\\0\\0\\1
    \end{array}
\right]$$ is equivalent to the equation $A^TPA+P=I$

In this question I approached to make $Q$ to $2\times 2$ matrix. but I couldn't get any idea.. I need you genius to help.

Comment: Do you mind to check your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939198/how-can-i-verify-i-uvt-1-iuvt-1vt-u

Comment: Yes. that was really good help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. $Q$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix. Try to understand what happens when $p_1=1$, and $p_2=p_3=p_4=0$. Then you will be able to find the first column of $Q$.
Can you take it from here?

P.S. Finally you will find that
$$Q=\left[
    \begin{array}
      \\
      a_1^2+a_1 &a_1a_3+a_1&a_1a_3+a_1&a_3^2+a_1
    \\a_1a_2+a_2 &a_1a_4+a_2&a_2a_3+a_2&a_3a_4+a_2
    \\a_1a_2+a_3 &a_2a_3+a_3&a_1a_4+a_3&a_3a_4+a_3
    \\a_2^2+a_4 &a_2a_4+a_4&a_2a_4+a_4&a_4^2+a_4
    \end{array}
\right]$$

Comment: I was not able to understand why you set P like that....I need to study more....even I couldn't understand model like $A^TPA+P=I$ ,$PA+A^TP=I$

Comment: @matthew $[1,0,0,0]$ is a vector of the canonical base.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operation we get

$$\operatorname{vec}(A^TPA + P) = \operatorname{vec} (I) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then, using linearity and the properties given on wikipedia:
$$(A^T \otimes A^T)\operatorname{vec}(P) + \operatorname{vec}(P) = \operatorname{vec} (I)$$
Rearranging gives
$$(A^T \otimes A^T + I_4)\operatorname{vec} (P) = \operatorname{vec}(I)$$
Which is what you require.

Comment: I'm surprised the vec operation suits this question so well!